# EGOTableViewPullRefresh - Unable to build due to linking issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pull-request

I am trying to use EGOTableViewPullRefresh in my ios6 project but I can't get past a linking issue when building. After including the source to my project, adding -fno-objc-arc flag to the EGORefreshTableHeaderView.m and then making all of the necessary changes to the source so that I can build with ARC (removing 'release' etc) I am running into the following linking issues:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CATransform3DIdentity", referenced from:
      -[EGORefreshTableHeaderView setState:] in EGORefreshTableHeaderView.o
  "_CATransform3DMakeRotation", referenced from:
      -[EGORefreshTableHeaderView setState:] in EGORefreshTableHeaderView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CALayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EGORefreshTableHeaderView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransaction", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EGORefreshTableHeaderView.o
  "_kCAGravityResizeAspect", referenced from:
      -[EGORefreshTableHeaderView initWithFrame:arrowImageName:textColor:] in EGORefreshTableHeaderView.o
  "_kCATransactionDisableActions", referenced from:
      -[EGORefreshTableHeaderView setState:] in EGORefreshTableHeaderView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Has anyone run into this problem using EGOTableViewPullRefresh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]You do need the QuartzCore library framework to be included for pull-to-refresh to link properly.

This is achieved by going to your Target page (click your target icon on the left column at the top of Xcode layout), select the "Build Phases" tab, click to open "Link Binary with Libraries" then click the '+' button, begin to type "QuartzCore" and select the QuartzCore framework.

That should fix these link errors for you.

Comment: Oh man... of coarse. I can see the imports now in the header file. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, I stumbled on this the first time too!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the QuartzCore framework added.